# Is there any way to implement database migrations in automated fashion using jenkins or free tool?

Tags: mysql, database

I have an application with 2 `environments` i.e. one is 'development' other is 'production'. Now the issue is that we used to db changes frequently to 'development' `db` but whenever we have to deploy the `production` `build` so we have to update manually all the table `scehma`, `stored procedures` etc. So is there any free tool or `jenkins` method through which i can write a `script` which will be executable when i have to deploy `production` `build` so then i will run that script and the updates of `development` db will sync with `production` `db`?

Comment: I love the way rails handles migrations and it looks like some people took the time to rip the guts out into a standalone gems maybe give these a look (I haven't tried any of them) https://github.com/thuss/standalone-migrations or https://github.com/jhollinger/otr-activerecord or https://github.com/rosenfeld/active_record_migrations

Answer (score 0):

There is no standalone tool you can do this but here are steps to make a database CI/CD :

1. first source control your database using git, there are bunch of tools for that purpose.
2. find a schema / data file compare tool which gives you delta file based on project folder with ability of to be run from command line , so you can automate it in Jenkins. something like [sqldelta](https://sqldelta.com/) or [dbforge studio](https://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/database-synchronization.html) , which are not free. you might find something free. or you can prepare them manually and go to the second step.
3. you can use flyway (free tool) to manage your migration script and even source control them easily
4. use Jenkins to automate the process.

Comment: and what about all stored procedures? how will i make a process to copy all those stored procedures form development db to production db?

Comment: This includes all data and schemes changes

Answer (score 0):

Use Apache NiFi(https://nifi.apache.org/) and schedule the jobs for Extraction. It can be scheduled thru windows or corn scheduler. It has so many sources and sink options so that you can configure it as per your need. Create first flow to extract data from source DB and output of this flow will be input of second flow. Second flow will read the output of first flow and load data to target DB. Its is opensource and has good UI support. We are also working on PoC for StreamSet(https://streamsets.com/) for cloud migrations.

Comment: So basically i want to migrate my schema changes and stored precedures from one DB to another DB so can it be done through your mentioned tool?

Comment: If you are interested in Schema and DB objects migration then please use Liquibase or Flyway. We have GitLab pipeline and from there we can deploy these changes to Dev, Pilot and Prod env. Both are compatible with Maven/Java/Jenkins. we are using both in different projects. Personally I like FlyWay since we are writing separate script for rollback. When you have DB version control objects you can add stage in your job in your pipeline to move it to Dev or Prod env. Use Version control for schema changes and objects and NiFi for DB data migrations.

Comment: could you update your answer with these suggestions? @TusharK

Comment: @mcint Usually we keep our Java or any other code in Git based repo. Then we raise a PR to push code in different environment. CICD pipeline will deploy this code in your respective environment. Lets consider your DB DDL DML scripts as code. You push your code and raise PR. Once PR is approved and code is merged, FlyWay/Liquibase will connect to DB from Pipeline and deploy newly added scripts to DB dev/test environment. It can be a simple java project or just Maven pom file with folder structure to keep DB Scripts. And create pipeline accordingly. Docker images are also available for both.